# White page by using the filter template_include

Tags: wordpress, filter, plugins

I working on my plugin and tried to override some templates.

If I visit the page **portfolio** my screen gives a whitepage.

This is my code

```
define("PLUGIN_DIR_PATH", plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
add_filter( 'template_include', 'plugin_tweak_template', 99);

function plugin_tweak_template( $template ) {
    if ( is_page('portfolio')) {
        $template = PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'required/templates/portfolio.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

I use this code in my plugin root file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the define path has a conflict.
**define("PLUGIN_DIR_PATH", plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));**

PLUGIN_DIR_PATH is a example in many tutorials but you can define this one time.

Is you have another plugin check the define name from this plugins if this is the same name you have a conflict.

Remember always: use variable names etc. by your own and prevent issues.